# App to check if other user is online

Tags: windows, android

I need to alternate with a friend in doing a job online. I just want a simple app that let me know if my friend is online and vice-versa. Something like facebook green dot next to a friend's name which can be activated and deactivated manually.

This way if I see my friend is working (green dot) I just wait until he goes offline to take his place. No needs for fancy features.

Which software can I use? 
Also an android app could be suitable for us.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Instant messaging clients will do it - from Skype, Viber, heck even the FB messenger will do this.

make your pick

Comment: Not everytime we're online we are working!

Answer (score 0):

Implement Broadcast Receiver Class as follows which will send broadcast whenever internet is online:

```
public class InternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean isConnected = new ConnectionDetector(context)
                .isConnectedToInternet();
        if (isConnected) {
            //user is connected 
        }
    }

public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

In Manifest define as :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.InternetReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
```